# Display Drivers in Fedora

Tags: linux, drivers, fedora, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

I am using **Fedora 22** and having problems with my **Nvidia GeForce GTX765M** driver. I cannot adjust my laptop screen brightness and cannot output video from hdmi. I did a little research here and on fedora forums and here are some points that might be useful to diagnose the problem:

- Nouveau driver is installed already

  ```
  sudo dnf install *nouveau*
  ```

  gives the result:

  ```
  Package xorg-x11-drv-nouveau-1:1.0.11-2.fc22.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
  Dependencies resolved.
  Nothing to do.
  Complete!
  ```
- xorg.conf has no entry related to backlight or nvidia:

  ```
  ls /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
  ```

  gives the result:

  ```
  00-keyboard.conf  50-synaptics.conf
  ```

  which are obviously related to keyboard and touchpad.
- /sys/class/backlight directory is empty.
- lspci related results are:

  ```
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
  ...
  01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M] (rev a1)
  ```
- Nvidia driver is suppressed (although i did try commenting that line and rebooting too, didn't work):

  ```
  cat /usr/lib/modprobe.d/dist-blacklist.conf
  ```

  gives:

  ```
  ...
  # framebuffer drivers
  blacklist aty128fb
  blacklist atyfb
  blacklist radeonfb
  blacklist i810fb
  blacklist cirrusfb
  blacklist intelfb
  blacklist kyrofb
  blacklist i2c-matroxfb
  blacklist hgafb
  blacklist nvidiafb #HERE IT IS!
  blacklist rivafb
  blacklist savagefb
  blacklist sstfb
  blacklist neofb
  blacklist tridentfb
  blacklist tdfxfb
  blacklist virgefb
  blacklist vga16fb
  blacklist viafb
  ...
  ```

Any other suggestions? I merged my two questions (backlight and hdmi) assuming both were stemming from same problem, but i may be mistaken in that. Thanks in advance.